# Half-Edge Collapse

Tags: criteria, mesh

I'm currently trying to implement a half-edge collapse in order to perform incremental remeshing. I'm dealing with a manifold mesh. Consider the following simple mesh:

[image]

The goal is to collapse a into b.

[image]

In this case however, this results in a non-manifold mesh

[image]

which I want to prevent. My question is:

**How can I do this in advance, i.e. perform a check before the collapse whether the collapse operation is safe?**

I've tried the criteria (link condition) from Hoppe, but both are fulfilled as it seems. Also, the only intersection of the one-rings of a and b is c, thus only one point as it is a boundary edge.

**Also generally speaking, what other checks do I need to perform to avoid an illegal collapse?**

Right now, I have the following criteria:

- if a and b are boundary vertices, the edge ab must be a boundary edge
- a, b and the third vertex of triangles adjacent to edge ab must be a valid triangle (link condition)
- if triangles adjacent to edge ab are boundary triangles, do not collapse if a is on the boundary edge
- if the intersection of the a-1-ring and b-1-ring is not equal to two (or one for boundary edges), do not collapse

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about general math/geometry, rather than about programming as defined by the [help].

Comment: This is fantastic example. Thanks for the illustration.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to look at this paper:

[Tamal Dey, Herbert Edelsbrunner, Sumanta Guha, and Dmitry Nekhayev. Topology preserving edge contraction.](http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/publ/86/n080p023.pdf)

I'm not sure which Hoppe's paper you are referring to (progressive mesh?) but Tamal Dey's link condition is different from the one you stated. Intuitively, an edge ab is collapsible if

```
one-ring(a) intersected with one-ring(b) == one-ring(ab).
```

For an edge ab, one-ring is the set of the other vertices of the faces sharing ab. Also in Tamal Dey's link condition, you need to take the dimension of the embedding space into consideration. (i.e. the link condition is different for an edge in 2d and in 3d). Many other work use this link condition to collapse edges without incurring topological errors.

What's confusing is from your example I couldn't really tell whether it's a mesh-with-boundary in 3d or 2d, or how "planar" it is. These factors determine whether the resulting mesh has a "folding" or not, e.g. triangle bcd is considered folded in 2d but could be fine in 3d if the mesh is not planar.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it's been a while since I posted this question. The example was meant to be simply 2d, with all vertices except `c` being boundary vertices. Just quickly going through the condition:
`one-ring(a) = {b,c,d}, one-ring(b)={a,c,e}, one-ring(ab)={c}`, which would mean `one-ring(a) intersected one-ring(b) = {c} = one-ring(ab)`, so the condition would be fulfilled even though bcd is folded, right?

Comment: Yes, in this case the link condition should be still fulfilled even though there is a geometric folding. The thing is, the condition is only meant to keep topology unchanged, not to avoid geometric artifacts. In order to prevent triangle from folding, I think you need to either nudge the affected vertices around, e.g. recompute vert c as some weighted sum of its one-ring, or really delay collapsing those edges that would incur large deformation

Comment: (this is also how the edge-collapse, or mesh-decimation framework works, using geometric errors to give each edge contraction a priority). I'm also working on something similar, but geometric distortion is not my concern since I'm only collapsing edge of length 0. Hope this discussion helps.

Comment: Thanks again for helping me out. So is there no way to do any check in advance whether the collapse operation is going to result in folding? I've seen several libraries doing this, but most of them perform checks after the operation and reverse it in case of folding. I've done this a year ago in the context of incremental remeshing within Matlab, and I wrote an OpenMesh wrapper for this purpose in case it helps anyone https://github.com/christopherhelf/isotropicremeshing.

Comment: I know those post are quite old, but how about checking the clock wise of resulted triangles for geometric distortion ?

Comment: @vcloarec Sure you can do this check, assuming you have the ability to undo the operation if it introduces non-manifold faces.

Comment: @vcloarec After a second I'm not sure how are you going to check for non-manifold which is topology issue with just geometric distortion?

Comment: @danielyan86129, my suggestion was only for geometric distortion, for non-manifold faces, there are other checks to make